# python how to select printer for print receipt

Tags: python-3.x

the following code is working successfully, i need to print receipts. i want to select printer to print receipts. in this code how can i add printer function. I need to printer selecting option separately.
i don't know which function using in this code.
i hope you will help for this,
Thanks im advance.

[image]

```
from tkinter import ttk
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import*

def update():
    listBox.insert('','end',value=('APL', t1.get(),t2.get(),t3.get()))
    listBox.insert('','end',value=('cPL', t4.get(),t5.get(),t6.get()))


def update():
    if t1.get() == '' or t2.get() == '' or t3.get() == '':
        pass
    else:
        listBox.insert('','end',value=('APL', t1.get(),t2.get(),t3.get()))
        listBox.insert('','end',value=('cPL', t4.get(),t5.get(),t6.get()))
    total = 0.0
    try:
        for child in listBox.get_children():
            total += float(listBox.item(child, 'values')[3])
            totText.set(total)
    except:
        pass
    lbl = Label(root,text=total,font=('helvetica',21))
    lbl.grid(row=5)

def print(): 
    tott = float(totText.get())
    top = Toplevel()
    top.geometry("300x300")

    top.config(bg="white")
    l = Label(top, text='-------RECEIPT-------')
    l.pack()
    l.config(bg="white")
    heading = Label(top, text='\tItem\tPRICE\tQTY\tTotal')
    heading.pack()
    heading.config(bg="white")

    for child in listBox.get_children():
        item = (listBox.item(child, 'values')[0])
        price = float(listBox.item(child, 'values')[1])
        qty = float(listBox.item(child, 'values')[2])
        tot = float(listBox.item(child, 'values')[3])
        item1 = Label(top, text=f'{item}\t{price}\t{qty}\t{tot}')
        item1.config(bg="white")
        item1.pack()

    tot = Label(top, text=f'Total\t{tott}')
    tot.config(bg="white")
    tot.pack()        

root = tk.Tk()
root.geometry('1000x600')

e8 = tk.Label(root,text="APL").grid(row=1,column=0)
t1 = tk.Entry(root)
t1.grid(row=1,column=1)
t2 = tk.Entry(root)
t2.grid(row=1,column=2)
t3 = tk.Entry(root)
t3.grid(row=1,column=3)

e9 = tk.Label(root,text="cPL").grid(row=2,column=0)
t4 = tk.Entry(root)
t4.grid(row=2,column=1)
t5 = tk.Entry(root)
t5.grid(row=2,column=2)
t6 = tk.Entry(root)
t6.grid(row=2,column=3)

global totText

totText = StringVar()

cols = ('Item', 'PRICE', 'QTY', 'Total')
listBox = ttk.Treeview(root, columns=cols, show='headings')

for col in cols:
    listBox.heading(col, text=col)
    listBox.grid(row=1, column=0, columnspan=2)
    listBox.place(x=10, y=300)

b = tk.Button(root,text='Update Listbox',command=update)
b.grid(row=3)
Button(root, text="print", command=print, height=3, width=13).place(x=850, y=120)

root.mainloop()
```

Comment: Why don't you save those result in pdf or excel format? You can print then and your data would be stored as history of transaction too

Comment: i want to direct print to thermal print receipt

Comment: Oh. try to press `CTRL+P`on your result. If you are able to print it, then it can be done programatically too

Comment: CTRL+P is not working..

Comment: That means you cant print it. If  you dont want to store your results in excel or pdf, you have another option which is to take screenshot of your screen and then print it because print works on images too. all via programatically

Comment: @Karthik He is looking for a way for the thermal printer to print this out, just like a normal receipt printed in shops, which i dont think is actually directly possible with tkinter? Maybe export the data and then do stuff with it. Automation might be the key here

Comment: @CoolCloud Thats what i mentioned..Either you can store it in pdf or excel and then print it or he can take screenshot of the result and then print it.. `pyautogui` would be the suitable library for him according to me

Comment: @Karthik I agree too.